# c# multithreading sending out 3 different threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I had a recent question about this however I am now getting an error which is "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable". The part underlined is the declaration of var Results.

All I am trying to do is send out these 3 different methods at the same time as they are all data work and will take some time. I figured asynchronously sending them out and then waiting for the return of the 3 parts would work best. Each method returns a datatable, and I am just trying to access what comes back.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
 async void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // need instance, virtual methods, may add overrides. 
        SchoolData CSD = new SchoolData();
        FData FD = new FData();
        GiftData GD = new GiftData();


        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CSD.getSchool()));
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => FD.getF()));
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GD.getGift()));

        var Results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the piece of code that is failing?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to have a `List<Task<DataTable>>` since your tasks all compute `DataTables`.  As it is you're storing  (non-generic) `Task` objects, meaning they aren't representing any results.

You'll also need to move the code into another method besides `Main` as it cannot be marked as `async`.